# how to create system which will listen for one rabbit MQ queue and then perform series of task through rabbit mq then reply

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want design such a system which will listen on rabbit MQ `#queue1`

1. it will take the message from rabbit mq
2. On message check for the type of request
3. it will create that type of packet
4. it will send the request on different rabbitmq #Queue2
5. wait for the reply
6. get reply and depending upon the reply it will put request one #queue3
7. again wait for the reply
8. get the reply
9. it will send consolidated reply to the first request came on queue1

Which type of spring-amqp  messaging system/technique i should use for this design and how ?(like Spring Remoting with AMQP or Message Correlation With A Reply Queue and correlation ID  )

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the Consumers of `#queue1` to wait for reply and then send it to `#queue2`

You can design steps as

1. Consumer will take the message from `#queue1`
2. On message check for the type of request
3. it will create message of that type
4. it will send the request on different rabbitmq `#Queue2`
5. Consumer of `#Queue2` would consume the message . depending on the processing result (which you would have sent as reply) , It would put request to `#queue3`
6. Consumer of `#Queue3` would consume the message . Consolidate the previous result with the current result,It would put request to `#queue4` with the consolidated result .
7. Consumer of `#Queue4` would consume the message . Consolidate the previous result with the current result,It would put request to `#queue5` with the consolidated result .
8. Assuming that final processing would be done on `#queue5` . Consolidate the current results with previous result and send it consolidated reply to `#replyQueue`

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

Comment: I want to execute some #pre and #post checks for each of the task depending upon the result/response of previos task , so i want response for every request that i have put on RabbitMQ queue.

so i want response for task2 from queue2 and depending upon the result i will do some post check on task2 then pre checks for task3 and then i will log a request for task3 on rabbit MQ #queue3